# Free/libre feed reader for Firefox OS that allows offline reading

Tags: open-source, offline, rss, feed-reader, firefox-os

I’m looking for a FLOSS feed reader for Firefox OS.

- All entries should be downloaded so that I can read them while being **offline** (text required, images optional).
- There should be a way to mark specific entries as **favorites**. All other read entries should get deleted somehow.
- It should be possible to read the entries **per feed** (instead of having *all* feed entries in the same list).
- It should **not** try to get the full text on the webpage when the feed only contains teasers.
- It should **not** stay active in the background (e.g., looking for feed updates on its own). It should only update the feeds and download their entries when I manually invoke it.
- It should support all common **feed formats**: Atom, RSS (RDF Site Summary), RSS (Really Simple Syndication), RSS (Rich Site Summary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at all free/libre feed readers I could find in the *Firefox Marketplace*:

- [**Alir**](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/alir) seems to be primarily an app for reading webpages offline; feed reader is only a bonus, and doesn’t seem to have many features because of that (yet at least).
- [**cloneReader**](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/clonereader-beta) didn’t work for me (and might lack offline support anyway).
- [**dogfeed**](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/dogfeed) made a nice impression, but requires [remoteStorage](http://remotestorage.io/) and [Sockethub](http://sockethub.org/) instances.
- [**FeedMonkey**](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/feedmonkey) requires a server (TinyTinyRSS, ownCloud News, or Pond).
- [**FeedReader**](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/feedreader) made a nice impression, but some feeds didn’t work. It seems that it can save entries for 4 weeks at maximum.
- [**FeedSpider**](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/feedspider): couldn’t test it, as it’s not reviewed yet, and the *Firefox Marketplace* requires a login for installing it.
- [**FireReader**](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/firereader) made a nice impression, but only supports the service *The Old Reader*.
- [**MyWebRSS**](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/mywebrss) made a nice impression, but requires a server: MyWebRSS API, ownCloud API, or Selfoss API.
- [**SimpleRSS**](https://marketplace.firefox.com/app/simplerss) made a nice impression, and was the only reader that could handle all feeds I tried.

While I’ll consider self-hosting a feed reader so that I can use dogfeed, FeedMonkey or MyWebRSS, these are not suitable solutions for this question.

For now, I’m using [**SimpleRSS**](http://www.user1.be/simplerss/).

It had the best typography of all tested apps and makes for a nice reading experience. This screenshot shows an article (the "npf.io" in the heading is the feed name):

[image: Screenshot of SimpleRSS’s interface: reading an article]

Features:

- You can read entries per feed, or have all entries in the same list ("Timeline").
- Very nice search: updates results while typing, searches also in feed entry bodies (not title only).
- Can import OPML (from Web or SD card) and export as OPML (to SD card).
- You can edit title and URL of added feeds (not all tested apps made this possible).
- When browsing with Firefox, you can add a feed URL to SimpleRSS via the Share option.
- You can scroll horizontally when the entries is too wide, e.g., for complex tables (wasn’t possible with some tested feed readers).
- You can configure the timeline to keep 50, 100, 200, 500 or 1000 entries. The oldest entry will be deleted when this threshold is reached. But …

Drawbacks:

- It’s not possible to mark entries as favorites, and there is no way to delete specific entries manually. So this means I can’t save entries forever.
- Hiding read entries is only possible globally, not per feed or on the fly.
- No pinch to zoom (but offers a button for zooming one level).
- Refreshing feeds is only possible globally, not for specific feeds only.

If SimpleRSS would get the ability to mark specific entries as favorites (which never get deleted), it would be a perfect match for my requirements.