# RSS reader addon for Firefox which keeps feeds

Tags: firefox, rss

I'm looking for a Firefox addon for Atom/RSS which is similar to [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10511/free-libre-feed-reader-for-firefox-os-that-allows-offline-reading):

- entries are periodically fetched and kept for a configurable amount of time (e.g. one month)
- it is possible to "bookmark" or "star" favorite entries which are kept indefinitely
- ideally, it should render stored entries even if no connection is available
- entries from different feeds should be kept separately and souldn't mix with bookmarks
- it should be possible to view the full article in a new tab

I know I can use Thunderbird for this, but it fails to render many websites correctly and I'd prefer to keep my logins (needed for some sites) in Firefox only.

Answer (score 1):

I've bumped into the exactly the same problem not so long ago. I tried numerous Firefox extensions, some of them were pretty decent, but then [electolysis](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis) arrived and Mozilla decided to disable support for the extensions that are not supporting multithreads, including the ones I've used for a while and invested some time in configuring them.

So I've decided to ditch RSS extensions and use a standalone app for that -- [QuiteRSS](https://quiterss.org/), at least until the guys at Mozilla sort the things out. QuiteRSS is also more configurable that Thunderbird's News Feed. It uses Webkit for rendering now, though the devs want to switch to chromium in the future.

Comment: Thanks for this! A standalone app is not what I have in mind, but this one runs on all platforms Firefox supports, so it's an option. I'll definitely check it out.